# Yii does not log with an infinite loop

Tags: php, logging, yii

I am not sure if this is the bug in yii or i am doing a wrong approach. I am creating a back-end process that runs without stop and logging is something that is crucial.

I created a console application. My logging works when I do this:

```
public function actionTest(){
         Yii::log( "testing", 'error', 'worker.*');
         return;
}
```

I am able to see "testing" logged into the file worker.log that is located in runtime folder>

However when I create an infinite loop, I don't see anything that is logged:

```
public function actionTest(){
       while(1){
             Yii::log( "testing", 'error', 'worker.*');
             echo 'running';
            usleep(5000000);
       }
}
```

The worker.log file is empty.

Here is the configuration setting for worker.log in console.php:

```
array(
   'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
   'categories' => 'worker.*',
   'logFile' => 'worker.log'
)
```

Comment: What do you mean "an infinite loop"? Can you post your code?

Comment: sorry, just realized that I forgot to add the loop. Please see my edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance reasons, by default Yii outputs log records at the end of the request OR when **CLogger::autoFlash** messages limit is reached IF **CLogger::autoDump** is set to **true**.

In your case this event never occurs. To fix it you have several options:

- configure CLogger to flush messages as soon as you log them, by setting **autoFlash = 1** and **autoDump = true**
- call **CLogger::flush()** method manually
- you can create your own logger class that flushes messages the way you need
- or use one of the existing implementations that flushes messages right away, like [this one](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/140/real-time-logging/).

Comment: Yes you are right. Seems like logging only works at the end of a request.

Comment: There is a flush command in CLogger, have you tried it?
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLogger#flush-detail

Comment: Thanks, @LaurentF, added it to my answer.